# InDesign CS6: How do I adjust individual corner options?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm trying to create a rectangle with two rounded corners and two pointy corners. I should be able to accomplish this by deselecting the "make all settings the same" icon in the Corner Options window, but for some reason, this icon is locked, and I can't seem to figure out how to unlock it (no, clicking on it doesn't work). I can adjust all four corners, but not each one individually.

[image]

Comment: Did you try creating a new document and creating the rectangle from scratch? Sometimes documents collect weird preference bits.

Comment: New document from scratch idea didn't work. The corners are still all locked so that you can only adjust all four identically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't round individual corners of a diamond shape... **the shape has to be rectangle to alter individual corners**.

Draw the rectangle, set the corner rounding options, **then** rotate it.

Comment: Ha! nicely done. the *screenshot* certainly cleared that up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the shape converted to a rectangle...

**Object > Convert Shape > Rectangle.**

Your yellow corner options should appear around the "rectangle" and thus allowing individual settings.

Hope this helps. This may only work for 4 cornered shapes.